# Why R Markdown does not import .csv files and says there is no such file at the directory

Tags: r, macos, csv, r-markdown

I use Mac OS, I try do read .csv files on R Studio but it keeps saying there is no such file at the current working directory. ( It was no problem in the past btw)
Here is what I tried.

I use R markdown, I read somewhere that sometimes Markdown has different working directory so use getwd().
Then I used list.files(), and the .csv  file is shown at the result.

Finally I tried R (instead of R Studio) and I got the same error.

I do not have the same problem with importing images.

So here is the all the codes I have used:

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("here")
library(tidyverse)
library(here)
my data <- readr::read.csv("../data/kitaplar.csv")

Error: '../kitaplar.csv' does not exist in current working directory ('/Users/bahar/yeni')


getwd()
list.files()

[1] "/Users/bahar/yeni"
[1] "data"            "images"          "instagram.Rmd"   "kitaplar.csv"   
[5] "r_datagirme.Rmd" "r_docs"          "yeni.Rproj"
```

I hope someone can help me.

I just want to add I carried file out of the data to see if it makes any changes. So this is not about file is not in the data folder.

Comment: That error isn't consistent with your command:  you asked to read `"../data/kitaplar.csv"`, and the error says it tried to read `"../kitaplar.csv"`.  I think you've got a typo somewhere or other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have better luck using the absolute path (or full path) instead of the relative path to the file.

On MacOS, select the file, press `Command + I` to open up the information pane, and copy the text portion of `Where`, which should give you the absolute path to the folder the file is in. Copy that to R, and add your file name. There are [other ways](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-copy-a-file-path-in-os-x/) to do it as well.

The major advantage of using the absolute path is that you don't have to worry about your current working directory when importing data.

Comment: So, when I press the  Command + I, nothing happened. But I tried to use here() info the write down the absolute path, and it worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your `list.files()` output, it appears that `"kitaplar.csv"`  is not in the `data/` directory. Instead, it is at the same "level" of the file structure as your R Markdown file (assuming that is `"r_datagirme.Rmd"` ).

By default, R Markdown assumes the folder that it is saved in is the working directory when it renders. So, if your R Markdown and your CSV are in the same directory, the following should work:

```
my data <- readr::read_csv("kitaplar.csv")
```

Additionally, I see that you have loaded the `here` package. However, you are not currently using this package. For a full explanation of R Markdown working directories and a comparison of the `here` package and other options to manage file paths, please see [this chapter](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/working-directory.html) of the *R Markdown Cookbook*

Comment: I tried it, and it did not work. But I  also need to learn how to use `here` package. So, thank you so much for the chapter.

Comment: Do you get the same error message or a different one?

Comment: I got the same error, but just  now I tried with a new working directory and files then it worked ( Wow) but when I put it back to folder it still doesn't see it. But if I use fullpath it works.